# How can I verify that refactoring preserves code flow, not just behavior?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, refactoring, static-analysis

Sometimes, I see if-statements that could be written in a better way. Usually these are cases where we have several layers of nested if-statements and I've identified a simpler way of rewriting the block of if-statements.
Of course the biggest concern is that the resulting code will have a different code flow in certain cases.

How can I compare the two code-blocks and determine if the code flow is the same or different?
Is there a way to support this analysis with static analysis tools? Are there any other techniques that might help?

Comment: not exactly that, but `cppcheck` will suggest you better alternatives to write your code if it finds that it's messy. Also, what you want is not possible because it could be used to solve the halting problem.

Comment: An alternate question might "is there any test coverage tool which can show that all paths are tested".

Comment: @user3477950 can it really be equivalent to the halting problem if it we are just talking about nested conditional blocks with nothing that could cause a loop?

Comment: Sorry, but voted to close: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."_ PS: Are you talking about cases where the compiler doesn't optimize the code anyway?

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala IMHO yes. But not sure. However, static analysis cannot *always* predict *everything* about a program, given that a program's run-time behavior is... well... **run-time** behavior.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem good, though I like this question.  Perhaps the OP should generalise it as a question about how best to safely re-factor this kind of code.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala: That's why I didn't down-vote the question: I, too, think it could be turned into a relevant, valid question

Comment: I tried to edit the question to make it more suitable.

Comment: Convert the original code into a test, and apply it to the refactored code.  It's almost TDD for free!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find some way to exercise all possible paths through the code that you want to refactor. You could

- write unit tests by hand
- use Daikon http://plse.cs.washington.edu/daikon/, which exercises code automatically and systematically to infer invariants (I haven't used it myself, but I have tried a commercial descendant targeted at Java)

Either way, use a code coverage tool to verify that you have complete statement and decision coverage. Use a coverage tool that reports the number of times each statement is executed during the coverage run. You might even be able to get [trucov](https://code.google.com/p/trucov/), which actually generates diagrams of code paths, to work.

Do your refactoring.

Run the coverage tool again and compare statement execution counts before and after the refactoring. If any statement execution count changed, the flow must have changed. The opposite isn't guaranteed to be true, but it's probably close enough to true for practical applications. Alternatively, if you got trucov to work, compare execution graphs before and after; that would be definitive.